# Is it possible to get a "push" when number of messages reaches threshold?

Tags: rabbitmq, push, message-queue, messaging, threshold

I want to check

1. What is the best practice to get the number of messages in a queue. 
   I know I can get it via queue.getMessageCount()
   I also know that you can get it as the monitor plugin gets it. is it an http request? or with the rabbitmqctl application.(JNI?) ?
   What is the best way if I want to react only when X messages arrive?
2. And more important - can I get the number of messages in a queue via push?

Can I declare a threshold to receive a push notification?
(e.g. get a signal every time I have 5000 messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use queue `x-max-length` http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

> Queue length is a measure that takes into account ready messages, ignoring unacknowledged messages and message size. Messages will be dropped or dead-lettered from the front of the queue to make room for new messages once the limit is reached.

So you can configure the  [Dead Letter Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and manage the messages rejected by limit exceeded.

> The reason is a name describing why the message was dead-lettered and is one of the following:
>   rejected - the message was rejected with requeue=false,
>   expired - the TTL of the message expired; or
>   maxlen - the maximum allowed queue length was exceeded.

I hope it helps

**EDIT****

The idea could be:

Subscribe a queue for example `_queue` on DLE so when a message arrives means your  is reached.

```
void hanlemymessage(msg){

.....

}


  //// consumer _queue
  public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
            BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws java.io.IOException {

               MyMessage m= new MyMessage(body)
               voidhanlemymessage(m)

              StartmyBulkConsumer()

    }
```

Now you can start your `work_consumer`.

```
    //// consumer work_queue
          public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                    BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws java.io.IOException {

                       MyMessage m= new MyMessage(body)
                       voidhanlemymessage(m)

                       if (msgcount.addandget()==mythreshold){
                          closeConsumer()

                         }
```

This could be one solution.

**Actually** I think that this logic should be delegated to the application:
For example the `work_consumer` always running and your application trigger your bulk function when reaches the .

Comment: Thanks. I can't see how it can assist me in working on bulks. Do you mean I can subscribe to a queue in the DLE and than when a message arrives - start to consume from the original queue that was filled? and then move the message back from dle to the queue? maybe I failed to understand...

Comment: @rails I modified the answer.I hope it helps.